# Youtube API V3 embed restrictions

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the youtube v3 data API.

On my website, however, I often get videos that are broken, and say:

**"This video contains content from UMG. It is restricted from playback on certain sites"**

How can I check for this restriction using the youtube API?

- Under the video status, it lists 'embedable' as TRUE.
- I also tried search() with videoSyndicated=true parameter, but that
  doesn't seem to work either.